# str_to_date() не распознаёт дату и время

Tags: mysql

Имеется строка `'10/01/2016 00:00'`, которую нужно привести к mysql типу DATETIME.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('10/01/2016 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i');
```

формат, вроде бы, правильный, а возвращет все равно NULL.  Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), спецификатор `%h` соответствует (цитирую):

> Hour (01..12)

у вас же указана в качестве часа строка `00`. соответственно, попытка её преобразовать в часы приводит к ошибке.

вероятно, часы у вас указаны в 24-часовом формате, и надо использовать спецификатор `%H`:

> Hour (00..23)

т.е., команда должна выглядеть так:

```
select str_to_date('10/01/2016 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете маску `%h` - это часы в Американском формате, разрешенные значения от 1 до 12 включительно. 0 часов не разрешено, т.к. это 12:00AM.

Используйте маску `%H` для времени в 24 часовом, т.е. с 00 до 23 формате.